# TextView in TableLayout Height

Tags: android, android-layout

I use `TableLayou`t to align controls and their labels. Both of style/rounded_label and style/rounded_value's height and width are `wrap_content`.

```
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
```

When TextView splits it's text to two rows, TableRow height isn't changed.
[image: Left Multi Line]

But when EditText has a multiple rows, TableRow wraps it.
[image: Right Multi Line]

I need TableRow to wrap text when TextEdit multiple line..

(I have tried ShrinkColumn)

Layout xml is :

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/frmPaymentTableLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableRow
                android:id="@+id/frmPaymentTrSerialCreditCardNo"
                style="@style/rounded_row" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/frmPaymentTvSerialCreditCardNo"
                    style="@style/rounded_label"
                    android:text="Card Nr" />

                <View style="@style/rounded_seperator" >
                </View>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/frmPaymentEtSerialCreditCardNo"
                    style="@style/rounded_value"
                    android:ems="10" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>
            </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

`TableLayout` handles all widths and heights of its children.  In fact, you can't even define `layout_width` for its children.  This may be the cause of your issues.

Try removing `layout_height` and `layout_width` from your views.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` inside your `TableRow` item, it will fits `TableRow` size according to its child's.

I think you missed the point of your implementation... I think you need to re-design your xml...

```
<TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/frmPaymentTableLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/frmPaymentTrSerialCreditCardNo"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/rounded_row" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/frmPaymentTvSerialCreditCardNo"
                        style="@style/rounded_label"
                        android:text="Card Nr" />

                    <View style="@style/rounded_seperator" >
                    </View>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/frmPaymentEtSerialCreditCardNo"
                        style="@style/rounded_value"
                        android:ems="10" >

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
                </TableRow>
```

Comment: TableRow has android:layout_height="wrap_content" already.. but not working.